# Cluster mode Netapp - Snapmirror change unix groups

Tags: nfs, synchronization, netapp

I'm trying to setup snapmirror between two cluster mode netapp filers.

However, one is in the US, the other is in China.

We have two different unix groups setup here, as a security measure.

i.e. we have group users.usa in the USA, and users.china in China.

users.usa cannot view users.china files, and vice versa, and nobody in china can be a member of users.usa/vice versa.

So can I snapmirror the users.usa data to china, and change the unix group of the files to users.china, i.e. is there a netapp option for that?

Also, by doing this, would I completely screw up the compression/snapmirror comparison algorithm, as the files would technically be different, no?

Thanks for this, we're rocking onTap 8.3 on both filers.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a snapmirror that's an active replication target, because it's a block level copy.

What you can do is clone it, and then modify the clone. You'd need to recreate this each snap iteration though.

https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1366832/html/volume/clone/create.html